# jquery button strange class behaviour

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created  jsfiddle here jsfiddle.net/ckAyF/

however after clicking first time it does add btn-success class
but when second time clicked why btn-primary event triggered?
please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use event delegation here:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-success', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
});

$(document).on('click','.btn-primary',function() {
    $(this).removeClass("btn-primary");
    $(this).addClass("btn-success");
});
```

You can shorten your code using **[toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** as well:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-success, .btn-primary', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-success btn-primary");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckAyF/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

I looked on your fiddle. I don't know why it doesn't work, but this code works.

```
<button id="my-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style ="margin-right:10px;"> </button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-btn').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('btn-success')) {
            $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
            $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("btn-primary");
            $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: This works for one button but how can I go with lots of buttons having the same behaviour?

Comment: You can put an additional class instead of the id #my-btn, and trigger the event for that class.